# How should I Execute this Python Script in powershell

Tags: python, powershell

> I've solved the problem. The problem is related my %PATH%

I have a script which work with an argument. In powershell I've tried the command you can see below;

```
.\dsrf2csv.py C:\Python27\a\DSR_testdata.tsv.gz
```

And also you can see the script below,

```
def __init__(self, dsrf2csv_arg):
    self.dsrf_filename = dsrf2csv_arg
    dsrf_path, filename = os.path.split(self.dsrf_filename)
    self.report_outfilename = os.path.join(dsrf_path, filename.replace('DSR', 'Report').replace('tsv', 'csv'))
    self.summary_outfilename = os.path.join(dsrf_path, filename.replace('DSR', 'Summary').replace('tsv.gz', 'csv'))
```

But when I try to run this script there is no any action. How should I run this script with a file? (example : testdata.tsv.gz)

Note : Script and file in same location.

Full Scritp;

```
import argparse
import atexit
import collections
import csv
import gzip
import os


SKIP_ROWS = ['HEAD', '#HEAD', '#SY02', '#SY03', '#AS01', '#MW01', '#RU01',
             '#SU03', '#LI01', '#FOOT']

REPORT_HEAD = ['Asset_ID', 'Asset_Title', 'Asset_Artist', 'Asset_ISRC',
               'MW_Asset_ID', 'MW_Title', 'MW_ISWC', 'MW_Custom_ID',
               'MW_Writers', 'Views', 'Owner_name', 'Ownership_Claim',
               'Gross_Revenue', 'Amount_Payable', 'Video_IDs', 'Video_views']

SUMMARY_HEAD = ['SummaryRecordId', 'DistributionChannel',
                'DistributionChannelDPID', 'CommercialModel', 'UseType',
                'Territory', 'ServiceDescription', 'Usages', 'Users',
                'Currency', 'NetRevenue', 'RightsController',
                'RightsControllerPartyId', 'AllocatedUsages', 'AmountPayable',
                'AllocatedNetRevenue']


class DsrfConverter(object):
  """Converts DSRF 3.0 to YouTube CSV."""

  def __init__(self, dsrf2csv_arg):
    """ Creating output file names """


    self.dsrf_filename = dsrf2csv_arg
    dsrf_path, filename = os.path.split(self.dsrf_filename)
    print(dsrf_filename)
    input("Press Enter to continue...")
    self.report_outfilename = os.path.join(dsrf_path, filename.replace(
        'DSR', 'Report').replace('tsv', 'csv'))
    self.summary_outfilename = os.path.join(dsrf_path, filename.replace(
        'DSR', 'Summary').replace('tsv.gz', 'csv'))

  def parse_blocks(self, reader):
    """Generator for parsing all the blocks from the file.

    Args:
      reader: the handler of the input file

    Yields:
      block_lines: A full block as a list of rows.
    """

    block_lines = []
    current_block = None
    for line in reader:

      if line[0] in SKIP_ROWS:
        continue

      # Exit condition
      if line[0] == 'FOOT':
        yield block_lines
        raise StopIteration()

      line_block_number = int(line[1])
      if current_block is None:
        # Initialize
        current_block = line_block_number
      if line_block_number > current_block:
        # End of block, yield and build a new one
        yield block_lines
        block_lines = []
        current_block = line_block_number
      block_lines.append(line)

    # Also return last block
    yield block_lines

  def process_single_block(self, block):
    """Handles a single block in the DSR report.

    Args:
      block: Block as a list of lines.

    Returns:
       (summary_rows, report_row) tuple.
    """
    views = 0
    gross_revenue = 0
    summary_rows = []
    owners_data = {}

    # Create an ordered dictionary with a key for every column.
    report_row_dict = collections.OrderedDict(
        [(column_name.lower(), '') for column_name in REPORT_HEAD])
    for line in block:
      if line[0] == 'SY02':  # Save the financial Summary
        summary_rows.append(line[1:])
        continue

      if line[0] == 'AS01':  # Sound Recording information
        report_row_dict['asset_id'] = line[3]
        report_row_dict['asset_title'] = line[5]
        report_row_dict['asset_artist'] = line[7]
        report_row_dict['asset_isrc'] = line[4]

      if line[0] == 'MW01':  # Composition information
        report_row_dict['mw_asset_id'] = line[2]
        report_row_dict['mw_title'] = line[4]
        report_row_dict['mw_iswc'] = line[3]
        report_row_dict['mw_writers'] = line[6]

      if line[0] == 'RU01':  # Video level information
        report_row_dict['video_ids'] = line[3]
        report_row_dict['video_views'] = line[4]

      if line[0] == 'SU03':  # Usage data of Sound Recording Asset
        # Summing up views and revenues for each sub-period
        views += int(line[5])
        gross_revenue += float(line[6])
        report_row_dict['views'] = views
        report_row_dict['gross_revenue'] = gross_revenue

      if line[0] == 'LI01':  # Ownership information
        # if we already have parsed a LI01 line with that owner
        if line[3] in owners_data:
          # keep only the latest ownership
          owners_data[line[3]]['ownership'] = line[6]
          owners_data[line[3]]['amount_payable'] += float(line[9])
        else:
          # need to create the entry for that owner
          data_dict = {'custom_id': line[5],
                       'ownership': line[6],
                       'amount_payable': float(line[9])}
          owners_data[line[3]] = data_dict

    # get rid of owners which do not have an ownership or an amount payable
    owners_to_write = [o for o in owners_data
                       if (owners_data[o]['ownership'] > 0
                           and owners_data[o]['amount_payable'] > 0)]
    report_row_dict['owner_name'] = '|'.join(owners_to_write)
    report_row_dict['mw_custom_id'] = '|'.join([owners_data[o]
                                                ['custom_id']
                                                for o in owners_to_write])
    report_row_dict['ownership_claim'] = '|'.join([owners_data[o]
                                                   ['ownership']
                                                   for o in owners_to_write])
    report_row_dict['amount_payable'] = '|'.join([str(owners_data[o]
                                                      ['amount_payable'])
                                                  for o in owners_to_write])

    # Sanity check. The number of values must match the number of columns.
    assert len(report_row_dict) == len(REPORT_HEAD), 'Row is wrong size :/'

    return summary_rows, report_row_dict

  def run(self):
    finished = False
    def removeFiles():
      if not finished:
        os.unlink(self.report_outfilename)
        os.unlink(self.summary_outfilename)
    atexit.register(removeFiles)
    with gzip.open(self.dsrf_filename, 'rb') as dsr_file, gzip.open(
        self.report_outfilename, 'wb') as report_file, open(
            self.summary_outfilename, 'wb') as summary_file:
      dsr_reader = csv.reader(dsr_file, delimiter='\t')
      report_writer = csv.writer(report_file)
      summary_writer = csv.writer(summary_file)

      report_writer.writerow(REPORT_HEAD)
      summary_writer.writerow(SUMMARY_HEAD)

      for block in self.parse_blocks(dsr_reader):
        summary_rows, report_row = self.process_single_block(block)
        report_writer.writerow(report_row.values())
        summary_writer.writerows(summary_rows)

    finished = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
  arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      description='Converts DDEX DSRF UGC profile reports to Standard CSV.')
  required_args = arg_parser.add_argument_group('Required arguments')
  required_args.add_argument('dsrf2csv_arg', type=str)
  args = arg_parser.parse_args()
  dsrf_converter = DsrfConverter(args.dsrf2csv_arg)
  dsrf_converter.run()
```

Comment: You could try going to your script folder in the _Powershell_ console and type: `python .\dsrf2csv.py testdata.tsv.gz`. But this relies on the fact that the _python.exe_ executable is located in one of the folders present in your _%PATH%_ environment variable. If this is not the case, specify it by full path  e.g.(as I don't know where you have _Python_ installed) `"C:\Python\3.5\python.exe" .\dsrf2csv.py testdata.tsv.gz` (or add the folder to _%PATH%_).

Comment: What observable action do you expect to occur and why? Your script does not do anything.

Comment: Write a test script check `which python version is incoming?` or type `#!"c:\Program Files\pythonXX\python.exe"` in first script line(`XX` not porn, related your used python version)

Comment: When i try to try this, a got ImportERrror
C:\Python27\python.exe .\dsrf2csv.py testdata.tsv.gz
ImportError: No module named site @CristiFati

Comment: @Goyo I've added full script now. I expect that the script convert my tsv data to the csv with some rules which are described in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In general to execute a python script in powershell like this `.\script.py` has two requirements:

1. Add the path to the python binaries to your `%path%`: `$env:Path = $env:Path + ";C:\Path\to\python\binaries\"`
2. Add the ending `.py` to the pathtext environment variable: `$env:PATHEXT += ";.PY"`

The latter will only be used in the current powershell session. If you want to add it to all future powershell sessions, add this line to your powershell profile (f.e. notepad `$profile`).

In your case there is also an issue with the python script you are trying to excute. `def __init__(self)` is an constructor for a class, like:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print "foo"
```

Did you give us your complete script?

Comment: I've added full script.